# Center div in page

Tags: html, center

I know this has been asked a thousand (million?) times, but for the life of me I can't figure out why I can't get a div to center on my page. Even with the HTML and CSS stripped down to the bare minimum.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm missing here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#branchSelect { margin: 0 auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="branchSelect">
            <h4 class="selectBranch">Select a Branch to View</h4>
            <select type="select" id="ddlBranches" class="selectBranch">
                <option id="defaultBranchesListItem" value="0">Select a branch...</option>
                <option value="1">Atlanta</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/YjvMs/1/).

Comment: try align="center" first -for sanity check

Comment: I added this page: http://www.eventidewebdesign.com/public/centerTest/table%20layout%20test.html for you guys to take a look at. The jsFiddle that Marcus posted works, but seemingly only with a small 300px width on the div. When I set the div to 1000px (the width of the body) the elements move over to the left again. Changing the div width to other values moves the div back an forth in different positions. What's going on here?!?

Comment: You set the width of the body to 1000px, so the 300px div is going to be centered within those 1000 pixels. You should set the width of the div to 1000px and never change the width of the body.

Comment: The width of the div and the body are **both** set to 1000px. Still no centering. I'm still not seeing what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

divs are automatically set to 100% width.

Just set the width of the div and use the `margin: 0 auto;` to center it on the page.

```
div#branchSelect {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Marcus & @ AJ, I added a width but that didn't do anything: http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/YjvMs/5/.

Comment: You forgot the whole `width: ` portion of the attribute. See my CSS in my answer, now look at yours.

Comment: Please see the comment I added to my OP. Your code worked, but changing the width does crazy things...

Answer (score 0):

Your div lacks a width property and so by default its with is 100%, so no matter what you do it gets streatched all the way accross the screen, so just assing a width property to your div and then set the margin as "0 auto" in style as shown by Marcus Recck

```
<body>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        centered content
    </div>
</body>
```